# Can't view Ubuntu like it should appear

Tags: icons

New to Linux and boy am I seeing that fact.  I'm wanting to try to have it set up so I can turn the computer and it starts up immediately with Ubunutu, from a flash drive.  I wasn't having any kind of luck doing that so I stumbled into the idea of worse case scenario...use VMware Player.  I tried starting a new machine and it seemed like it was going to work.  Everything loaded in and I came up to the main screen.  One problem there was no icons.  Just the blank start up screen.  I tried scrolling the cursor around the screen toward the area where the icons should appear and black boxes popped up as I was scrolling down the screen.  I decided to click on the boxes and see what would happen.  Sure enough there were icons under those black boxes and I could open up LibreOffice, Firefox, system settings, etc.  I didn't know what I was opening, until after I clicked on it, but I could open it.  I looked here on askubuntu and saw it mentioned that it might be a hardware issue and to switch to Unity2D.  I tried and that failed.  In further reading in Getting Started with Ubunutu 12.10, there is no Unity2D option anymore.  Yes, I have 12.10 installed.

The main screen when it appears isn't full size, it's about 3/4 of the screen.  As I scroll down the 'icons' sometimes the screen flashes other times I lose the wallpaper on Ubunutu altogether.

First impressions are lasting impressions and currently my first impressions of Linux are good ones to say the least...but I'm still willing to progress forward.

How do I get to a normal operating interface?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing Ubuntu from inside windows using a virtual dvd. Use [Daemon Tools Lite](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/products/dtLite) or some other virtul disk software to mount the iso you downloaded to a virtual disk, then simply double click it in Computer (it might also run automatically) and just follow the installation instructions. You need to have a separate partition. If you don't have one, google how to shrink your windows partiton using disk management in Windows.

I've had the same problems you're having with VMWare, and if you want the full Ubuntu experience without said problems, you should just install it like a regular OS as I mentioned above.